# Что не так с регуляркой

Tags: php

Не работает регурялка в php может кто-то подскажет почему?:

```
$re = '/\[\{[^\}\]]*\}\]/im';
$str = '<p>line1_test<br />
             [{notEmpty|address_line2|<br />
            }] line3_test [{notEmpty|address_line3|<br />
            }]</p>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

пробую на regex101.com, все норм

---

ожидаю найти `[{notEmpty|address_line3|<br/>}]`

Comment: добавил текст в пост

Comment: А пример входных данных?

Comment: переменная $str

Comment: @user340555 Попробуйте так. Вроде работает всё. `\[\{[^\}\]]*\}\]`

Comment: @StanislavHmelevsky  такоже как и было?

Comment: @user340555 Да. А не такое как сейчас. Такое как сейчас, как раз не работает)

Comment: @StanislavHmelevsky проверил твое, не работает

Comment: ......... PHP_EOL

Comment: @Bloom извини не понял?

Comment: Перевод каретки может где в строке

Comment: выполнил код из вопроса - ожидаемый результат найден. как вы проверяли и как пришли к выводу что оно не работает?